# How to make querys when tou have many to many relationships between models?

Tags: sails.js

i am trying to make a game. I need tu create a Match. I think the problem on this Way. The User create a Match. In a third table I save playerId and gameId. When another user join the match, I save again, playerId and gameId. Then, I make a query with player with gameId in common, and start the game.

first, One User may have many Games. second, One Match may have many Games. this is the Match model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
        type: 'string'
    },

    description: {
        type: 'string'
    },

    game: {
        collection: 'game',
        via: 'gameId',
    }

  }
};
```

This is the User model:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
        type:'string'
    },

    email: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    password: {
        type: 'string',
    },

    passwordConfirmation: {
        type: 'string'
    },

    passwordEncrypted: {
        type: 'string'
    },

    creator: {
      collection: 'game',
      via: 'playerId'
    },

    toJSON: function(){
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        delete obj.passwordConfirmation;
        delete obj._csrf;
        return obj;
    }
  }, beforeCreate: function(values, next){
        console.log("Acabo de entrar a eforeCreate");
        var password = values.password;
        var passwordConfirmation = values.passwordConfirmation;

        if(!password || !passwordConfirmation || password != values.passwordConfirmation) {
            var passwordDoesNotMatchError = [{
            name: 'passwordDoesNotMatchError',
            message: 'Las contraseñas deben coincidir'
        }]
        return next({
            err: passwordDoesNotMatchError
            });
        }

        require('bcrypt').hash(values.password, 10, function passwordEncrypted(err, EncryptedPassword){
            values.EncryptedPassword = EncryptedPassword;
            next();
        });
    }
};
```

This is the Game model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    gameId: {
        model: 'match'
    },

    playerId: {
        model: 'user'
    }



  }
};
```

finally, this is my controller:

```
module.exports = {

createMatch: function(req,res){

        var matchObj = {
            name: req.param('name'),
            description: req.param('description'),
        }


        Match.create(matchObj, function(err, match){
            if(err){
                console.log("el error fue: " + err);
                return res.send(err);
                } console.log("Entro en create");
                 return res.json(match);
        })

        var gameObj = {
            gameId: 'aclaration: I dont know how do I get the match.id',
            playerId: req.session.me
        }

        Game.create(gameObj,function(err,game){
            console.log("entro a GameCreate");
            if(err){
                return res.send(err);
            } return res.json(game);
        })
    }


};
```

I can create the Match, but Game.create send this error:

_http_outgoing.js:344 throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.'); ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Somebody can help me? probably, I have many errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things here:

1. Having an explicit `Game` model is not required in Sails. It can manage it implicitly, unless you want to store more information than just `gameId` and `userId`. So, you can just do away with `Game` model.
2. Please refer for async programming: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Below code should work for you. Hope it helps.

```
module.exports = {
  createMatch: function(req, res) {
    var matchObj = {
      name: req.param('name'),
      description: req.param('description'),
    };

    Match.create(matchObj, function(err, match) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("el error fue: " + err);
        return res.send(err);
      }
      console.log("Entro en create");

      var gameObj = {
        gameId: match.id,
        playerId: req.session.me
      };

      Game.create(gameObj, function(err, game) {
        console.log("entro a GameCreate");
        if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }
        return res.json(game);
        // return res.json(match);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you friend, its works perfectly. Why do you want to store more information than gameId and userId you need a more table? And otherwise it is not necessary

Comment: A _join_ table is needed to store many to many relationship between Match and User. If only information to be stored is `matchId` and `userId` (an `id` of the table) then Sails manages it without having explicit model. However, if more attributes are needed in join table then Sails doesn't support it as of now. So a join table is there in both cases, it is just case of declaring it explicitly or framework managing it implicitly.
Many-many relationship: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/many-to-many